# Edit and add button for UITableView in ViewController

Tags: swift, uitableview, ios8.3

I have a little problem, I want to add a function to two `BarItems` in my `UINavigationBar`, which is placed above the `UITableView` in a normal `ViewController`. I'm very new to programming so can you please give me the complete code that I need? The functions I want to have are:

1. An edit button so I can delete and change the data of a cell (title + subtitle)
2. An add button so I can add a new cell to my `UITableView`. Maybe also a function that points to another `ViewController` where I can type the data for Title and subtitle to save it afterwards.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For editing record:**

You cannot get the cell that your planning to edit using button on `UINavigationController`, the buttons should be placed at the same cell on your `UITableview` to edit that specific cell. and in this way you need custom `UITableviewcell`.

**For creating new record :**

First link the button to your `UIViewController` class as Action.
You can append the array that your using to fill the `UITableview` and then call your `UITableview` like to refresh the data:

```
self.tableview.reloadData()
```

**For presenting another `UIViewController`:**

First drag new `ViewController` in your `storyboard` and link the button on the first `ViewController` into your new `UIViewController` and choose segue as "Show".

To save your data its a big topic you have either `NSUserDefaults` or `CoreData` so Google it.

**Note :** linking means by pressing ctrl-drag with mouse to your target.

**Update :**

Download your sample from here : https://yadi.sk/d/EJf610XWhkxDT

Comment: Thank you for responding! But I don't really get it because English is not my original language and I'm very new to programming... Is it possible to provide a sample code file? Maybe an entire Xcode project? Because it's easier to compare it with my code. Thanks for helping out!

Comment: What is your mother language ? i may help with it ? i might help with half of your project ! but not for all because we don't write code to share, you have to try and show us what you have and then we can help !

Comment: My mother language is Dutch @Aaoli

Comment: @LOLXDXPLOL , I've updated the question if it work well , then accept the answer :)

Comment: I can't see anything? :( I've opened the project you send me, but all I see is a blank ViewController and a standard(/new) .swift file :(

Comment: @LOLXDXPLOL , did it work ? if yes then accept the answer otherwise let me know whats missing ! thanks

Comment: I think I'm doing something wrong with my cell... When I type something in the textfield to get a new cell in my tableview, and click on the button that saves the information, then still nothing shows up in the UITableView :( @AaoIi

Comment: @LOLXDXPLOL, i tried it many times before i sent it. i will check again :)

Comment: @LOLXDXPLOL, you may download the file again and its for sure working :)

Comment: Yes indeed it's working in your file 100%, but i'm overlooking something because when i use your code in my project, it does not work so.. Xcode doesn't give any errors, i don't know it anymore.. Guess I have to learn a lot before I can start programming! @ AaoIi

Comment: @LOLXDXPLOL, Sure programming is not just copy and paste and you should learn the concepts first before deep into programming. you may upload your project somewhere and if you want i can integrate it for you. Thanks !

Comment: I'm not home now but i'll send you a link ASAP, are you jailbroken? If you want, then I can send you a copy of my app so you can install it on your jailbroken device, it's only for personal use because there are already a lot of apps like mine (digital shoppinglist) with way more features. Just wanted to learn some basics by developing this little app :) Thanks for helping me so much! I really appreciate it! @AaoIi

Comment: @LOLXDXPLOL , you may download your project working as i promised and please delete the link of your project from here..  Download link : https://yadi.sk/d/DYRe6ewohvwTp. btw the issue was with storyboard where tableview in Connection inspector wasn't connected for Datasource and delegate. the data actually exist but because the view isn't connected to the code. enjoy :)

Comment: Thanks! As soon as I have acces to my mac I'll download it! @AaoIi

Comment: I've downloaded it, can you delete your comment please? (The one with the URL) Thanks for helping me! @AaoIi